# Finding out Postgresql credential on EC2 deployed with Rubber

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, amazon-ec2, rubber

I deployed a Rails app using Rubber to EC2.
I am just using the default postgresql config.
https://github.com/rubber/rubber/blob/master/templates/postgresql/config/rubber/rubber-postgresql.yml

Does anyone know what the default credentials are?

[image]

Comment: are you trying to access the database from the EC2 box or from your local machine? EC2 instances use security groups to block most ports (which is a good thing)

Comment: Yes, from local machine. I can deploy from local machine fine.

Comment: postgres will be running on port 5432 and it should be blocked by default with EC2 box, you deploy on port 22 (SSH), if you look at your security groups on the EC2 box it will have open 22 and 80 you would need to add 5432 (I personally would not do this for production deploys) - also you might need to modify pg config to allow connections from your IP

Comment: O i understand what you mean. I'll try that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Directly from **rubber-postgresql.yml**:

```
db_user: "#{app_name[0,16].downcase}"
db_pass:
db_name: "#{app_name.downcase}_#{Rubber.env}"
```

So your username is the first 16 characters of your app name(or the full name, if less than 16 characters) down cased, your password is blank, and your database is your app name down cased followed by '_' and the environment.  In your case the environment is probably 'production'.

As far as the port and hostname, try leaving them as the default and see if that works.

Comment: I would like to note that, there was no way to find the password. I had to create another user on EC2 with PG with privileges I need.